# I am new to Prolog. I have tried to develop a major selection simple expert system, but I am stuck

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want to be able to let users choose a few options and not all to get the hypothesis to show. Example: The user is interested in computers, programming, and technology but not apps, i still want the system to show that user can major in Information Technology.

This code is able to run in swi-prolog.

```
go:-
    hypothesis(Major),
    write('I believe that the student can major in '),
    write(Major), nl,
    write('GOOD LUCK '),
    undo.

/*Hypothesis that should be tested*/

hypothesis(informationTechnology) :-
    informationTechnology, !.

hypothesis(informationTechnology_or_medicine) :- 
    informationTechnology_or_medicine, !.

hypothesis(medicine) :- medicine, !.

hypothesis(hospitality) :- hospitality, !.

hypothesis(business) :- business, !.

hypothesis(law) :- law, !.

hypothesis(unknown). /* no diagnosis*/

/*Hypothesis Identification Rules*/
informationTechnology :-
    verify(computers),
    verify(apps),
    verify(technology),
    verify(programming),
    write('Courses to choose from:'), nl,
    write('1: Computer Science'), nl,
    write('2: Information Systems'), nl,
    write('3: Security Technology'), nl,
    write('Please wear warm cloths Because'), nl.

informationTechnology_or_medicine :-
    verify(computers),
    verify(science),
    verify(communication),
    verify(problem_solving),
    verify(research),
    verify(technology),
    write('Courses to choose from:'), nl,
    write('1: Computer Science'), nl,
    write('2: Information Systems'), nl,
    write('3: Security Technology'), nl,
    write('These are the available courses.'), nl.

medicine :-
    verify(science),
    verify(health),
    verify(research),
    verify(helping_people),
    write('Courses to choose from:'), nl,
    write('1: Nursing'), nl,
    write('2: Medicine'), nl,
    write('3: Physiotherapy'), nl,
    write('These are the available courses.'), nl.

hospitality :-
    verify(helping_people),
    verify(management),
    verify(communication),
    verify(planning),
    write('Courses to choose from:'), nl,
    write('1: Hotel Management'), nl,
    write('2: Culinary arts'), nl,
    write('3: Human Resources Management'), nl,
    write('4: Public Relations'), nl,
    write('These are the available courses.'), nl.

business :-
    verify(money_making),
    verify(apps),
    verify(economy),
    verify(communication),
    write('Courses to choose from:'), nl,
    write('1: Business Administration'), nl,
    write('2: Accounting and Finance'), nl,
    write('3: Marketing and E-commerce'), nl,
    write('4: International Business'), nl,
    write('These are the available courses.'), nl.

law :-
    verify(law),
    verify(justice),
    verify(government),
    verify(politics),
    verify(reading),
    write('Courses to choose from:'), nl,
    write('1: Criminology'), nl,
    write('2: Political Science'), nl,
    write('3: Psychology'), nl,
    write('4: Forensics'), nl,
    write('These are the available courses.'), nl.

/* how to ask questions */
ask(Question) :-
    write('Do you have interest in:'),
    write(Question),
    write('? '),
    read(Response), nl,
    ( (Response == yes ; Response == y)
    ->
    assert(yes(Question)) ;
    assert(no(Question)), fail).

:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.

/*How to verify something */
verify(S) :-
    (yes(S)
    ->
    true ;
    (no(S)
    ->
    fail ;
    ask(S))).

/* undo all yes/no assertions*/
undo :- retract(yes(_)),fail.
undo :- retract(no(_)),fail.
undo.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another hypothesis like this:

```
hypothesis(informationTechnology_without_apps) :-
    informationTechnology_without_apps, !.
```

and a new hypothesis identification rule:

```
informationTechnology_without_apps :-
    verify(computers),
    verify(technology),
    verify(programming),
    write('Courses to choose from:'), nl,
    write('1: Computer Science'), nl,
    write('2: Information Systems'), nl,
    write('3: Security Technology'), nl,
    write('Please wear warm cloths Because'), nl.
```

Comment: @Tiffanycats - Does that answer your question?